# How to use PoWA at a backup database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm giving a try on PoWA, but I've got a little problem.

My Postgres database is running on AWS RDS.

PoWA needs HypoPG in order to suggest indexes.

But RDS doesn't support HypoPG extension. So I had to install PoWA at my backup database (outside RDS).

The problem is: PoWA isn't analyzing the restored database. It can't recognizes any data. If I execute some SQL queries manually it works though.

Is there something that I can be missing?

And, when I tried Ankane Dexter, I could show it the log files path (dumped at the backup database in parallel). Is there a way to do so in PoWA?

Thanks.